# For which $n$ is $2s \equiv 0\pmod n$ and $2s-2 \equiv 0\pmod {n-1}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

For which $n$ is

\begin{align*}
2s \equiv 0\pmod n \quad&\text{and}\quad 2s-2 \equiv 0\pmod {n-1} \\
\end{align*}

Where $n$ and $s$ are both positive integers, and $s \ge 3$
If someone could please solve this and explain how they got to the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that you can rewrite the second modulus equations as:

$$\quad 2(s-1) \equiv 0\pmod {n-1}$$

Looking at the both of the equation, we can see that for any value of $s$, both $2s$ and $2(s-1)$ would return a value of $0$ when taken modulus $2$.

Now, if we let $n = 2$, then:

$$2s \equiv 0\pmod 2$$

Which is true. We can also see that:

$$\quad 2(s-1) \equiv 0\pmod {1}$$

Which is also true.

Note that no other value of $n$ would **always** yield $0$ for every integer value of $s$. Only modulus $2$ would work.

Therefore, $n = 2$.

Comment: $n=2$ works for all $s$ but it isn't quite clear that this is the whole question. For example Given $s$ or $n$, $n=s$ is a solution. And $s=55, n=10$ is a different kind of solution, and $s=9, n=3$ works too.

Comment: @MarkBennet I understand your interpretation. To me it seems like he wants a solution that satisfies **all** $s$.

Comment: Yes sorry I know the the question was not well put. Varun is right, I meant all $s$

Comment: That's fine - there are lots of pairs which work and that is interesting in itself. I'm glad you hit the right interpretation.

Comment: I am actually going to post another question, something similar, can I send you a message when I post it so that you could maybe take a look at it?

Comment: @MarkBennet could you please take a look at my new post

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really shown what you've already done or what you know. But here is a (generous) hint.

Your two equations are equivalent to saying that there are positive integers $a$ and $b$ for which $$2s=an$$ and $$2s-2=b(n-1)$$If you eliminate the right term from these two equations you should be able to make good progress.

Answer (score 0):

Can you find a number near $2s$ that is a multiple of both $n$ and $n-1$?

Answer (score 0):

2s = 0 (mod n) : 2s = an

2s - 2 = 0 (mod n-1) : an -2 = 0 (mod n-1) : an -a + a -2 = 0 (mod n-1) :

a-2 =0 (mod n-1 ) : a = 2 (mod n-1) : a = t (n-1 )

2s = an : 2s = t(n-1)(n)

2s -2 = 0 (mod n-1) : t(n-1)(n) - 2 = 0 (mod n-1) : -2 = 0 (mod n-1) :

n-1 = 1 or 2 : n=2 or n=3

If n=2 , it satisfies the two condition

If n=3 : 2s = 0 (mod 3) : s=0 (mod 3): s= 3t

2s- 2 = 2(3t)-2=0 (mod 2)

So the only answers are n=2 , n=3